# are the following questions related to the probability of two events false?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following exercise: let $A,B$ be two events with $P(A)=1/2,P(B)=1/3$.

Are the following true or false?

a) $P(A-B)=P(A)-P(B)$

b)$B \subset A$

c) $P(A \cup B) \geq 1/2$

d)$A$ and $B$ are independent

(c) is clearly true as $A \cup B \supset A$ hence $P(A \cup B) \geq P(A)=1/2.$

But the other questions seems not to have enough data in order to be answered (in particular we cannot find $P(A \cap B)$), so they are false. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You have give examples where a) and b) fail. Consider $(0,1)$ as the sample space with Lebesgue measure Let $A=(0,\frac  12)$ and $B=(\frac 2  3,1 )$. Note that $P(A-B)=\frac 1 2 \neq \frac 12 -\frac 1 3$. Also, $B $ is not contained in $A$.